# Datatable plugin remove rows in DOM on paged tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a problem with the JQuery plugin Datatable , in fact I use this plugin to display tables and I also use the jspdf plugin to generate  beautiful pdf of my tables. Moreover, I also generates csv files (myself and without plugin) from the data in these tables. But I notice that, when the table is paged, rows that are not in the current page are not in the DOM.
But the plugin JSPDF and my algorithm to generate my csv are based on the elements of the DOM.

So, I want to know if there is a solution to leave hidden lines in the DOM with the datatable plugin when I change the current page.

Thanks a lot !!!!

**EDIT :** 
As davidkonrad said in comment, dataTable pagination is based on the concept of removing and injecting dom nodes. But you can easily extract all nodes by table.rows().nodes()

Comment: No, dataTable pagination is based on the concept of removing and injecting dom nodes. But you can easily extract all nodes by `table.rows().nodes()`...

Comment: Oh I see, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

When you go to each page, the datatable is getting redrawn. Hence what you have to do is wait until the table is drawn and then perform any of your tasks as shown below.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
      exporPdf();
      exporCSV();
    }
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Very good tips, but I think that if I call every time my tasks when the table is drawn like generating the pdf or the csv and if I have a lot of rows this can become heavy as process (I don't know but I guess).
But It's a very good tips for me and I would see if I use your solution or the davidkonrad's tip.

Comment: Even if you have many rows, it will draw only the rows to the current page DOM. So based on your no of rowd per page i.e 10, 25, 50, 100 it will draw only those rows, not whole rows from your data set

Comment: Humm I see, but in my case I want to generate pdf or csv with the whole rows. Maybe I don't understand your answer